# Emulator not displaying image on button click android

Tags: android

Please bear with me on this I'm new to android programming. I was trying to show  an image on a button click in android but unfortunately my emulator is not showing the required output. Here is my layout.xml file

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >


<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
    android:text="Button" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

main_activity.java

```
package com.example.app1;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
Button button;
ImageView image;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
         }


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}


public void addListenerOnButton() {

    button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

    button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {


                  image.setImageResource(R.drawable.optimus);

        }

    });


}
```

}

I have included the image file under /res/drawable-mdpi. When I try running on emulator it does not show image on button click. Is there any problem with the code?

Comment: you dont even have a button in your java file let alone a click listener or image

Comment: I did not get u. Please can u edit my code and point my mistakes. Thx in advance for anticipating.

Comment: You don't have an **ImageView** in your layout. How do you pretend to put an image on a non existing object? and you also don't have a control named **textView1** ... `android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView1"` OR shall I presume that you **mutilated** your layout? Can you show it **entirely**?

Comment: oohh i got the fix added imageview1 as suggested by u also had forgot to write addListenerOnButton(); in main_activity.java thanks dude for ur help.

Comment: @Darpit If it helped in solving your problem, please mark my answer as accepted. :)

Comment: @DerGolem your answer helped me in solving my problem but unfortunately don't have enough reputation to mark it accepted.

Comment: @Darpit you don't need any reputation to accept an answer: http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer - just check the tickMark near the answer. And it will give you +2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you have an ImageView called **imageView1**,
You have to assign it, before using it.

So change this:

```
    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0)
    {
        image.setImageResource(R.drawable.optimus);
    }
```

to this

```
    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0)
    {
        image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
        image.setImageResource(R.drawable.optimus);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

In your onCreate() method write this please :

```
Button theButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
theButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

theButton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.optimus);
        }
```

Comment: Let me know if this works and also delete your addListenerOnButton() method when you try this.Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You have to write onclick method like this code and also you need to call addListenerOnButton method in the onCreate() method

```
package com.example.app1;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    Button button;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        addListenerOnButton();
     }


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
// Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}


public void addListenerOnButton() {

    button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

    button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {


              button.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.optimus);

    }

    });


}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/background" <!-- you're adding this here -->
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >


<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
    android:onClick="showImage" <!-- you're adding this here -->
    android:text="Button" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Then in the .java file...

```
Package com.example.app1;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
Button button;
ImageView image;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
         }


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}


public void showImage(View view) {
    RelativeLayout background = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.background);
    background.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.optimus);
}   /* This is a whole new section of code to replace the onClick listener */

}
```

Since you're already using the XML Layouts, try to use the built in onClick listener whenever possible. You can do this by naming a function in your .java file called `yourFunctionName` with a single argument of `(View view)`.
Then, in your XML, you need to point to it by adding `android:onClick="yourFunctionName"` for the view that needs the onClick method.

Lastly, you never had the image you were referring to actually pointing to anything. You simply said that the object "image" now used "R.drawable.optimus" but that Image was never used! So instead, I just pointed to placing it in the background of your RelativeView. If instead you wanted it in a separate image, you'll have to add an `ImageView` to the XML file and set the background resource for the `ImageView` the same way.

Best of luck on learning Android!

Comment: I think your solution follows best coding practice by using built in onClick listener. Thanks for the explanation it means a lot to a newbie.

Comment: Hey, we've all started from the beginning. Even when you're "experienced" we're still all newbies at heart. If my answer helped, please remember to upvote and "accept" the answer. Thanks.